# Why not passing arguments to event functions?

Tags: meteor

Instead of always declare variables and find dom elements in an event such as scroll...
I have a template which has to know the scroll position to move some dom elements
according the view, but I've thought it's inefficient always call a find once one pixel
moved with scroll. What's the nice solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really one. You just have to wait for a scroll event and pass the event data to your function.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good plugins that listen for scroll events that meet certain criteria. Jquery waypoints has even been [packaged for meteor](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/jquery-waypoints2).